# EF migration script generation fails in Azure DevOps with exit code 2147516545

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I use the below command to generate the db migration script for my EF Context.

```
dotnet-ef migrations script --idempotent --output db-migrations.sql --no-build --verbose
```

This works fine locally, but on Azure DevOps build, fails with the error

```
The process 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 2147516545
```

No other errors/details, even with `--verbose` flag.

I can run `dotnet ef` and all the SDKs are present.

This works fine if I don't specify the `--no-build` option.

My build agent specification is `windows-latest`.

Ideally, I want to run this as the MSBuild `PostBuildEvent` of my database project, where I don't need to trigger the build again, and each Migration will have changes in the commit if it were to be different from the last.

(I understand that a build doesn't have to run for a given commit, and I will also have changes in the models/db context anyway)

Currently I have to first build the DB project as part of migration script generation, then build the solution in CI.

Answer (score 0):

Having a similar issue here, error MSB3073: The command "dotnet ef migrations script --idempotent --nullable --no-build --output D:\a\1\a/packages\Drln.Sql.sql --configuration Release --verbose" exited with code 1.

Locally also running fine

Comment: This is probably some bug. I haven't gotten around to setting up a minimal reproduction example to open an issue on github. IF you do have one, I think this is the right place to raise it.
[https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues}(https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues)

It is possible this may go away with EF 8